# How to add a timestamp prefix to logs in tf_logging?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a TensorFlow code, and I wonder how do I add a timestamp prefix to all of my logs.

One option is:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
logging.info(f'{timestamp}: some info')
```

I would like to have an output like this:

`INFO: 10:52 some info`

However, this requires me to remember it every time.
Is there a way to tell tf_logging to do this automatically?

Comment: May tf.timestamp serves your purpose. For few examples on the library with log info you can find [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/111150/tensorflow.timestamp).Thanks